# Should I prefer call destroy, or free mebmers manually, if allocation failed

Tags: c, struct, coding-style, abstract-data-type

Assuming I have an ADT, and some functions:

```
typedef struct myADT_t *myADT;
struct myADT_t {
    T1 *m1;
    T2 *m2;
};

myADT myADT_create() {
    myADT new_myADT=malloc(sizeof(*new_myADT));
    if (!new_myADT) return NULL;
    if (!(new_myADT->m1=malloc(sizeof(T1)))) {
        free(new_myADT);
        return NULL;
    }
    if (!(new_myADT->m2=malloc(sizeof(T2)))) {
        free(new_myADT->m1);
        free(new_myADT);
        return NULL;
    }
    //put some values in *m1 and *m2
    return new_myADT;
}

void myADT_destroy(myADT var) {
    if (!var) return;
    free(var->m2);
    free(var->m1);
    free(var);
}
```

I was told, that if the last allocation failed, I can call `myADT_destroy`, instead of free `new_myADT->m1` and `new_myADT` manually. However, it seems to me that although it will work, I shouldn't call `myADT_destroy` with a not-successfully-created object. Also, if I will add members to `myADT_t`, it may make things difficult.

What should I prefer?

Comment: Call the function you provided for that purpose. If you don't do that, you end up duplicating code unnecessarily. DRY.

Comment: Right now, prefer fixing your code; it has numerous compilation errors. Outside that, if the allocation assigned to `m2` fails the result will be a NULL value, which is acceptable to pass to `free()` as a no-op. Likewise if you initialize `m2` to NULL (one way or another) *prior* to entering the `m1` and `m2` allocation segments, you could invoke your destroy function in the event `m1` failed as well. As far as preference, prefer to never leave indeterminate conditions and *either* will work, equally well. *I* prefer keeping eggs in a single basket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take care to initialize the structure you allocate to zero (either explicitly or by using `calloc`) then you can call your `myADT_destroy` function on failure. The C specification explicitly allows `free` to be called with a `NULL` pointer.

Doing it that way, you can simplify the `myADT_create` function substantially, and also creates some symmetry.

Answer (score 3):

By using `myADT_destroy` instead of all the `free()` when `myADT_create` fails, you just need to maintain one function if you need to add members to the structure. The C standard explicitly says that calling `free(NULL)` has no effect.

Of course, this implies that you will never add any other functionality that may have side-effects in the destroy function. This is mostly a matter of taste though, both solution will work and both have some minor potential inconvenience.